# Lineup two Textviews as they need the space or distribute them even in the parent

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have tried with `LinearLayout`/`layout_weight` or `RelativeLayout` but could not make the layout behave as intended.

What I want to do, is a layout with two `TextViews` lined up horizontally and a delimiter in between. The (containing) layout has a constant maximum width, but may be smaller than that (but not larger). The width of the two `TextViews` should depend on their content, but also should have an upper boundary, so that they all fit together into this layout.

This is a visualization of the two cases:

a) both `TextViews` fit into their layout container and should be lined-up with the delimiter in between. Below, the containing layout is defined by the outer brackets and *may* be larger than the `TextViews`.

```
[[abcdefgs][delim][12334345]             ]
```

(container)layout width may be `wrap_content` or `fill_parent`

b) both `TextViews` do not fit into the (maximum) width of their layout container. They should then be distributed evenly inside their layout (with its maximum width). The text of the `TextViews` is then truncated.

```
 ..... 50% .....         ..... 50% .....
[[abcdefghijk...][delim][123456789012...]]
```

Someone knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want(as your question is ambiguous) but see if this layout helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#99cc00" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

where the `View` between the two `TextViews` represents the delimiter. Insert more text in the two `TextView` to see the space they take.

Comment: Well. If the Textviews take less space than their parent has, it works fine. With more text, the vertical space distribution (textA|delim|textB) is about 70%|30%. Both (textA, textB) are truncated but not equal. So its better than my version with a relativelayout (aligned from left to right) where only the textB is truncated.

Comment: @Chilibeta When I tested the layout I used the same(exact) text for both `TextViews`(like `"sdfjfdsfsdfbdjsfbdjfbdsjkfbdsjf"`) and it worked(you could try and test it). I guess the two `TextViews` having different width makes the `layout_weight` useless.

Comment: @Chilibeta After running some tests, I don't think you can achieve that type of layout in a xml layout file. The reason that I say this is because you'll eventually have to use `layout_weight` somewhere and this will force your `TextViews` to have the same width when they shouldn't(for example: when the second `TextView` is way bigger than the first one a huge gap will show between the first `TextView` and the divider as the `layout_weight` will be divided 50%). I haven't tested anything but you could try to arrange the `TextViews` in code, but that will easily turn into something messy.

Comment: That is what I also think. The param layout_weight only shares the empty space, that is left, and does not limit the space.

Comment: I have similar issue, and after several attempts to resolve it in xml end up with custom layout, based on LinearLayout, see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044155/textview-height-wrap-content-but-not-more-than-30-percent-of-parent/25507987#25507987